# include blank : true not working in select rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
<%= select :used_car, :car_make_id, @all_makes.map { |m| [m.title, m.name] }, {:include_blank => true,:prompt=>"Select Make"}%>

<%= select :used_car, :car_model_id, [], {:include_blank => true,:prompt=>"Select Model")}, size: 10, :class=>"form-control select"%>
```

Car models list updating on basis on car make selection
Issue is that when I select car make, prompt of car model remove and first option come

how i resolve it?

Comment: is the double `=> =>` a typo?

Comment: updated :).............

Comment: you have any solution?

Comment: Please share controller and `js.erb` file (if any).

Comment: Unfortunately i do not understand the question well enough :( If you can formulate it with more detail and maybe add some more information i can help you out

Answer (score 0):

Here is the documentation.

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormBuilder.html#method-i-select

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-select

Try `f.select :car_model_id, ...` instead. Also try using `nil` for `choices`, or `[[]]` for `choices`.

But first, you have an extra stray parenthesis ')' in this line:

> <%= select :used_car, :car_model_id, [], {:include_blank => true,:prompt=>"Select Model" **)** }

You have to remove that parenthesis. It doesn't go with anything.